# Brackets IDE not working on ubuntu 21,10

Tags: 20.04, crash, 21.04, adobe-brackets

Brackets IDE no longer opens on Ubuntu 21.10 - Just shows a white screen on opening and it's stuck like that no matter what, forever.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/tag/release-1.14.1) version of Brackets since I was on Ubuntu 20.04 after solving an [installation issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14786) using [this](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14786#issuecomment-491285972) solution.

Everything worked well and lit even on Ubuntu 21.04 and intially on 21.10 .

I'm not sure whether its a package update or kernel update that broke Adobe Brackets for me, either way it's like **my life depends on it** so someone **please help out**. ( I've mistakenly autoremoved older kernels so i can't really test by booting to an older kernel )

**I've already tried all available versions of brackets including the one at snap store** with no hope. (issue is reproducable with the snap version too)

**I've also tried running brackets as root**

Any help would be appreciated :)

``````
                          ./+o+-       karthik@knair
              yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 21.10 impish
           ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.13.0-16-generic
       .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 23m
     .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2608
    o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.1.8
   .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1080
.++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 40.0
/+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Mutter
\+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: 
.++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
.+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Numix-Circle
\+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Roboto 11
`:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 47G / 83G (60%)
.o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics @ 6x 2.375GHz
/osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0, 5.13.0-16-generic, LLVM 12.0.1)
````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 2882MiB / 7364MiB
`oo++.
``````

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is in pre-release testing. Issues with 21.10 should be discussed in the pre-release testing channel and the bug tracker (not here) until after release in October 2021.

Comment: For reliable development you have to use LTS version of Ubuntu like 20.04 LTS. Reinstall it and enjoy.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here.

Comment: The current state of *impish* is nearing beta, where the focus is on *bug hunting, bug reporting & bug fixing* so all issues with *impish* (what will be 21.10 on release) should be on bug trackers so any issues are fixed prior to release. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   Note:  As the program is a 3rd party one; the issue should likely be raised with the provider of that code.

Comment: Another thing is Adobe has killed support for brackets. They will not update or patch it any longer, and it is likely you will have a lot of issues with it as newer and newer Ubuntu releases come by.

Comment: See updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 21.04 and upcoming 21.10 you can install Brackets using the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/download/release-1.14.1/Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb

dpkg-deb -R ./Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb Brackets
sed -i 's/libcurl3/libcurl3 | libcurl4/' Brackets/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b Brackets Brackets-fixed.deb
sudo apt install -f ./Brackets-fixed.deb
```

We should note that 21.10 has [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1944468) in Glibc. To avoid use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mwhudson/devirt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then reboot and continue to use Brackets as it was planned.

Really the problem is wider - currently many Electron-based applications are affected: RStudio, Slack and VScode.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're god !